# Can I re-order build queue on hudson ci?

Tags: hudson

TeamCity has a very easy interface to re-order the build queue. Simply drag and drop.

Is there any way to re-order or prioritise build queue on hudson ci servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, not yet.

There is the [issue 833](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-833) which ask for this kind of feature since 2007, and there have been [recent development](http://fisheye.hudson-ci.org/changelog/Hudson/?cs=26610) in the code base in that direction, based on the [`QueueSortingHandler`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/jvnet/hudson/main/hudson-core/1.335/hudson-core-1.335-javadoc.jar!/hudson/model/Queue.QueueSortingHandler.html).

But I don't know if any plugin has already taken advantage of that feature.